# Write a query Display Dept Name , Job Name , "count of employees in job for each dept" & "Count of employees in dept"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to display the count of employees in job for each dept and count employees in dept. My desired output is like this:

```
DNAME                JOB                    Count(*)    Count(*)
-----                ---                    --------    --------
SALES                Manager                       3           5
ACCOUNTING           SALESMAN                      4           2
```

How can I do this? Can I use a sub query?

Comment: do u have dept and job as seperate tables

Comment: Is this your home work question ??

Comment: Yeah both r from seperate tables

Comment: We really need to see your DB structure to help you. If you can add that , please flag your question for moderator review.

Comment: The DB structure is a Standard tables EMP and DEPT tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get what you're looking for with the "Group by Cube" syntax.

```
SELECT d.DNAME, e.JOB, COUNT(*)
  FROM
EMP e JOIN DEPT d ON d.DEPTID = e.DEPTID
GROUP BY CUBE(d.DNAME,e.JOB);
```

Comment: May be. but the DNAME is coming from DEPT table and JOB is from EMP table.

Comment: I f i want to display the percentage of the both counts in the query..then the query needs to be written in diff way